# Next.js dynamic route one of provided list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a `Next.js` application with pages structure.
I want to add a prefix to all route but this prefix only can be one of `['A', 'B', 'C']` otherwise should return `404` page.

```
.
└── pages
    └── [prefix] <------ I want this to be either A or B or C.
        ├── page-1
        ├── page-2
        └── page-3
```

I expect to have this structure at the end.

```
/A/page-1
/A/page-2
/A/page-3

/B/page-1
/B/page-2
/B/page-3

/C/page-1
/C/page-2
/C/page-3
```

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs **pages router** does not support nested routing, which means at the time only one page can be matched/rendered (you may consider migrating to **app router** which gives you better control and you can easily handle it in there)

with that being said, the best you can do is to check the values in the nextjs middleware, and if the prefix parameter value is not valid redirect the user to a 404 page:

```
// middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - A
     * - B
     * - C
     */
    '/((?!A|B|C).*)'
  ],
}


// if it matches, it means the URL is not valid, so we redirect the request
export function middleware(request) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/404', request.url))
}
```

my personal recommendation is, that you prefix the route with another segment (like `/product`, this way you don't run issues with the middleware)

another option that you have is to create a function that checks for the parameter (the prefix in your example) and returns a response based on that, the problem with this is that you have to call this on every page that is going to be children of your prefix route

```
// utils/index.js

export function validatePrefix(prefix) {
    const validPrefixes = ["A", "B", "C"]
    return validPrefixes.includes(prefix)
}
```

```
// in all of these pages
// pages/[prefix]/page-1/index.js
// pages/[prefix]/page-2/index.js
// pages/[prefix]/page-c/index.js

import { validatePrefix } from "~/utils"

export const getServerSideProps = ({ query }) => {
    const isValidPrefix = validatePrefix(query.prefix)
  
    if (!isValidPrefix) {
      return { notFound: true }
    }
}
```